# Template class with container with pointers to itself

Tags: c++, templates

Is the following possible :

```
template<class  Container>
class TreeNode
{  

 Container mChildren;
}

TreeNode<std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<TreeNode>> myTreeNode;
```

Comment: What does your compiler tell you?

Comment: The following error is issued : error C3203: 'TreeNode' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not like you did. TreeNode is not a class but a class template.
I am in a hurry now so this might not be the most simple or elegant way, but it is possible:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Container {};

template<class  Container>
class TreeNode
{  
  Container mChildren;
};

class TreeNodeWrapper;

typedef TreeNode<std::vector<TreeNodeWrapper*> > recursiveTreeNode;

class TreeNodeWrapper : public recursiveTreeNode {
};

recursiveTreeNode myTreeNode;
```